# Custom control не реагирует на INotifyProperryChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, usercontrol, windows-10-mobile

Проект C# UWP Windows 10

Описал контрол на основе `TextBox`, при инициализации `Binding` срабатывает, однако на INotifyProperryChanged никак не реагирует. В шаблоне контрола пишет следующее:

*"Свойство "Symbol" не является свойством DependencyProperty. Для использования в разметке неприсоединенные свойства необходимо предоставить целевому типу с доступным свойством экземпляра "Symbol". Для присоединенных свойств в объявляющем типе должны быть представлены статические методы "GetSymbol" и "SetSymbol"."*

Код контрола:

```
public sealed class CurrencyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public CurrencyTextBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CurrencyTextBox);
    }

    public string Symbol
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CurrencySymbolProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrencySymbolProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrencySymbolProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Symbol", typeof(string), typeof(CurrencyTextBox), 
        new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSymbolChanged)));

    private static void OnSymbolChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((CurrencyTextBox)d).Symbol = (string)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

Строка из шаблона (тут же пишет ошибку описанную выше):

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="SemiBold" Text="{TemplateBinding Symbol}" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: А покажите весь шаблон, пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD http://pastebin.com/X7D5F2dr копия шаблона `TextBox` с еще одним полем

Comment: У вас там `<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">`, поменяйте. Должно взлететь.

Comment: @VladD Там `<ControlTemplate TargetType="Controls:CurrencyTextBox">` а `button` внутри  `<Grid.Resources> <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">`, по идее не должно влиять

Comment: Хм, и правда. Сейчас гляну.

Comment: Странно, у меня вот (под WPF, правда) ругается на `{TemplateBinding Header}`, `{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}` и `{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}`, а не на `Symbol`.

Comment: @VladD У меня просто в словарь со значениями для них есть. Тут все таки основная проблема - что значение не обновляется в контроле если возникает NotifyPropery. Пересмотрел кучу мануалов, вроде бы все правильно делаю...

Comment: Не, подождите, странно как-то. Является ли `Header` свойством у `TextBox` или `CurrencyTextBox`?

Comment: А сообщение об ошибке означает, что код вообще не должен компилироваться.

Comment: @VladD Ну у меня нормально работает. Мож специфика UWP? http://prntscr.com/b52yql Смотрите скрин. Компилируется нормально

Comment: А, понял, кажется. Написал ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в определении dependency property.

Нужно так:

```
public string Symbol
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(SymbolProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SymbolProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SymbolProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Symbol", typeof(string), typeof(CurrencyTextBox),
        new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSymbolChanged)));
```

Разница в названии статического поля, оно важно.

С depednency property лучше не переименовывать их вручную, а пересоздать при помощи сниппета `propdp`.

---

И судя по всему, вам вовсе не нужно `OnSymbolChanged`, вы там снова присваиваете уже присвоенное значение.

Comment: Ошибка пропала, но свойство все равно не обновляется. Binding работает только один раз, при инициализации

Comment: Обновление `Binding` сработало при `Mode=TwoWay`, Не понятно почему, но я очень рад что хоть как то работает ))

Comment: @SYL: Но у вас же нету `NotifyPropertyChanged`? В коде только dependency property.

Comment: @SYL: Дописал ответ — кажется, вам не нужен метод `OnSymbolChanged`.

Comment: Cпасибо огромное за помощь. Походу разобрался что к чему

Comment: @SYL: Пожалуйста!